# Why aren't my Qt5 language translations loading?

Tags: qt, cmake, internationalization, qml, qt5

I am trying to write a simple qml application with language translations using CMake and although the application runs, it never shows translations.  I'm on a Linux platform with CMake version 3.22.2 and Qt version 3.15.2 Here is the directory structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── silly.qrc
    └── qml
        ├── silly.qml
        └── translations
            ├── qml_de.ts
            ├── qml_en.ts
            └── qml_fr.ts
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(silly VERSION 1.0.0)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

### src/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Qml Quick LinguistTools REQUIRED)
set(TRANSLATIONS 
    qml/translations/qml_en.ts
    qml/translations/qml_fr.ts
    qml/translations/qml_de.ts
)
qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${TRANSLATIONS})
qt5_add_resources(QRC_RESOURCES "silly.qrc") 

add_executable(silly main.cpp 
    "${QRC_RESOURCES}"
    "${QM_FILES}"
)
target_compile_features(silly PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
set_target_properties(silly PROPERTIES AUTOMOC ON AUTORCC ON)
target_link_libraries(silly PRIVATE Qt5::Quick Qt5::Qml)
target_include_directories(silly
    PUBLIC
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:.>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}>
)
install(TARGETS silly)
```

### src/main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/qml/silly.qml"));

    return app.exec();
}
```

### src/silly.qrc

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource prefix="/qml">
        <file alias="silly.qml">qml/silly.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

### src/qml/silly.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    Button {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 20
        text: qsTr("Hello")
    }
}
```

### src/qml/translations/qml_de.ts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="de_DE">
<context>
    <name>silly</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="../silly.qml" line="11"/>
        <source>Hello</source>
        <translation>Hallo</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

### src/qml/translations/qml_en.ts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="en_US">
<context>
    <name>silly</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="../silly.qml" line="11"/>
        <source>Hello</source>
        <translation type="unfinished"></translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

### src/qml/translations/qml_fr.ts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="fr_FR">
<context>
    <name>silly</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="../silly.qml" line="11"/>
        <source>Hello</source>
        <translation>Bonjour</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

It builds and runs with no errors, but when I attempt to test with this:
`LANGUAGE=fr src/silly` I get a button that says "Hello" instead of a button that says "Bonjour".  I've been trying to figure this out for hours which also leads me to the secondary question:  how does one generally troubleshoot Qt language translations?  This is my first time and I could find no documentation on that.

Comment: Where do you load your translations with [QTranslator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html)? See also [here](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML).

Comment: I am attempting to create something like this: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/examples/qml/qml-i18n?h=5.15 but using CMake instead of qmake.  That code doesn't explicitly load `QTranslator` either.

Comment: On my Linux QtCreator Project Run Environment it uses `LANG` instead, and indeed changing that leads to a different UI language without me setting a language dynamically (which I have implemented on my project). Also, there is `".UTF-8"`, not sure it is needed

Comment: For the other program I mentioned above, running with `LANGUAGE` works.  Perhaps you can explain why that is?

Comment: You are right, `LANG` also works. But I must say that my project does a QTranslater::load at the beginning, like: `translator_.load(QLocale(), "qml", "_", ":/qml/translations/")`. Without that line `LANG` does not work

Comment: QTranslator is not necessary if you place qml_<language>.qm files to i18n subfolder of main qml location and are happy with the  language pointed by default locale and don't need to support dynamic language change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty badly documented stuff which works magically with ready-made example using dedicated qmake configuration parameter `embed_translations`. I advice you to take a look into the original example's build dir where .qm files and a special qrc file `qmake_qmake_qm_files.qrc` get generated.

You don't need to use `QTranslator` unless you want to support dynamic language switch. At startup, QML runtime automatically loads a translation file *qml_<language_COUNTRY>.qm* (qml_xx_XX.qm where xx is ISO639 and XX is optional ISO 3166 code) from the `i18n` subdirectory of the root QML file, based on the system language, if it finds one.

You need to get your .qm files to `qrc:/qml/i18n/` folder because your main qml file is in `qrc:/qml/`.

With `CMake` you can do it as follows:

Add a new qrc file, e.g. *cmake_qm_files.qrc* to your project

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/qml/i18n">
        <file>qml_de.qm</file>
        <file>qml_en.qm</file>
        <file>qml_fr.qm</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Get CMake to copy the qrc file to binary dir where .qm files get created

```
configure_file(cmake_qm_files.qrc ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} COPYONLY)
```

Get qrc file resource compiled and embedded to your executable

```
add_executable(silly main.cpp
    ${QRC_RESOURCES}
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_qm_files.qrc
)
```

I typically use QLocale for translation testing as follows:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QLocale systemLocale = QLocale::system();
QLocale::Language language = systemLocale.language();
QLocale::Country country = systemLocale.country();
qDebug() << "System locale language:" << language << ", country:" << country;

// TEST: change default locale by removing comments below
// language = QLocale::French;
// country = QLocale::France;
language = QLocale::English;
country = QLocale::Australia;
QLocale locale(language, country);
qDebug() << "Changing default locale to language:" << locale.language() << ", country:" << locale.country();
QLocale::setDefault(locale); // TEST: set default locale to something else than system locale

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming much of what I had experimentally derived.  I decided to document what I learned for anyone interested:  https://github.com/beroset/qml_translate_experiment